# How can I break the tie from my MySQL query using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am creating a pageant scoring system using PHP ang MySQL or PhpMyAdmin in XAMMP. I have somehow manage to get the rankings of the candidates using MySQL but there are cases to get ties. How can I break the tie from the result of my query using PHP?

The ranking of the candidates are according to their scores in a category where there are 5 judges and 9 candidates. So I really don't know what to do or how to solve it in PHP.

What if I supposedly wanted C9 to be at the first rank instead of C4?

Here is my Database... Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS score (
 candidate_no varchar(5) NOT NULL  ,
 category_no varchar(5) NOT NULL  ,
 judge_id varchar(5) NOT NULL  ,
 score int(3),
 PRIMARY KEY (candidate_no,category_no,judge_id),
 KEY score_fkey (judge_id),
 KEY score_fkey3 (category_no)) ;



INSERT INTO  score  (candidate_no,  category_no,  judge_id,  score) VALUES
('C1', 'cat1', 'J1', 17),
('C1', 'cat1', 'J2', 15),
('C1', 'cat1', 'J3', 17),
('C1', 'cat1', 'J4', 18),
('C1', 'cat1', 'J5', 19),
('C2', 'cat1', 'J1', 17  ),
('C2', 'cat1', 'J2', 15  ),
('C2', 'cat1', 'J3', 16  ),
('C2', 'cat1', 'J4', 18  ),
('C2', 'cat1', 'J5', 18  ),
('C3', 'cat1', 'J1', 15  ),
('C3', 'cat1', 'J2', 20  ),
('C3', 'cat1', 'J3', 19  ),
('C3', 'cat1', 'J4', 16  ),
('C3', 'cat1', 'J5', 19  ),
('C4', 'cat1', 'J1', 19 ),
('C4', 'cat1', 'J2', 20  ),
('C4', 'cat1', 'J3', 18  ),
('C4', 'cat1', 'J4', 18  ),
('C4', 'cat1', 'J5', 19  ),
('C5', 'cat1', 'J1', 18  ),
('C5', 'cat1', 'J2', 16 ),
('C5', 'cat1', 'J3', 18  ),
('C5', 'cat1', 'J4', 18  ),
('C5', 'cat1', 'J5', 18  ),
('C6', 'cat1', 'J1', 20  ),
('C6', 'cat1', 'J2', 16 ),
('C6', 'cat1', 'J3', 16  ),
('C6', 'cat1', 'J4', 16  ),
('C6', 'cat1', 'J5', 17  ),
('C7', 'cat1', 'J1', 11 ),
('C7', 'cat1', 'J2', 12  ),
('C7', 'cat1', 'J3', 14  ),
('C7', 'cat1', 'J4', 15  ),
('C7', 'cat1', 'J5', 17  ),
('C8', 'cat1', 'J1', 15  ),
('C8', 'cat1', 'J2', 16  ),
('C8', 'cat1', 'J3', 18  ),
('C8', 'cat1', 'J4', 17 ),
('C8', 'cat1', 'J5', 17  ),
('C9', 'cat1', 'J1', 19  ),
('C9', 'cat1', 'J2', 19  ),
('C9', 'cat1', 'J3', 19  ),
('C9', 'cat1', 'J4', 19  ),
('C9', 'cat1', 'J5', 18  );
```

This is my query:

```
select      sum
            ,candidate_no
            ,@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank

from(  

select      sum(score) / 5 sum
            ,candidate_no
from        score
where       candidate_no = 'c1'

union
select      sum(score) / 5 sum
            ,candidate_no
from        score
where       candidate_no = 'c2'

union
select      sum(score) / 5 sum
            ,candidate_no
from        score
where       candidate_no = 'c3'

union
select      sum(score) / 5 sum
            ,candidate_no
from        score
where       candidate_no = 'c4'

union
select      sum(score) / 5 sum
            ,candidate_no
from        score
where       candidate_no = 'c5'

union
select      sum(score) / 5 sum
            ,candidate_no
from        score
where       candidate_no = 'c6'

union
select      sum(score) / 5 sum
            ,candidate_no
from        score
where       candidate_no = 'c9'

) a , (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
order by sum desc
```

The Result would be..

```
sum       | candidate_no | rank
18.8000   | C4           |    1
18.8000   | C9           |    2
17.8000   | C3           |    3
17.6000   | C5           |    4
17.2000   | C1           |    5
17.0000   | C6           |    6
16.8000   | C2           |    7
16.6000   | C8           |    8
13.8000   | C7           |    9
```

Comment: Just to clarify - that's the desired result right? Even though candidates C4 and C9 have the same score, C4 wins the tie?

Comment: Why are you using a UNION instead of `GROUP BY candidate_no`?

Comment: Maybe you can add a `preference` column, set it to 1 if you want it to be the first in case of equal scores. Sort the scores on `preference`.

Comment: Simple, run it on [`sqlfiddle`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b20b/1/0) and you'll get the desired outcome. ;p _just adding a ref to sqlfiddle so any who want to play with it can_

Comment: @Barmar : well, because I am not so good in queries. I will use it. Thanks.

Comment: @Pieter: I see, I would try. Thanks.

Comment: @Strawberry: Well, it is,  but how can I choose C9 instead? is it possible to change the rankings thru PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JHaasie77 has a good approach, use the `candidate_no` as an orderer (which then comes down to an alpha-numeric sort order) making 9 first when you use descending order. (likewise, C9 would be last if you used ascending order). If there's no further disqualifiers, then that's the easiest route.

If you're making the order decision based on another metric, you probably want to change your table around to add some other column(s) you can order by. (Maybe it's by the "home-town hero" vs the "visitor", or by age with youngest matches first--who knows.) But any other detail would need to be added to the database so you could then use it to create a preference in the result.

with that said, you can slim down that query a bit by using a `GROUP BY` instead of union. this also makes it dynamic enough that if you had more candidates in the future, the query would automatically re-adjust. So, your long query now becomes:

```
SELECT      sum
            ,candidate_no
            ,@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM        (
              SELECT      SUM(score) / 5 SUM
                         ,candidate_no
              FROM        SCORE
              GROUP BY    candidate_no
            ) a
            , (
              SELECT @curRank := 0
            ) r
ORDER BY    sum DESC
            ,candidate_no DESC
```

Which basically means that for every unique `candidate_num` it will sum the score and divide by 5. The above also adds the second orderer for `candidate_num` making `C9` appears first [as seen here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b20b/5/0).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second ORDER BY variable, so it becomes "ORDER BY sum desc, candidate_no desc" if you want it to order by sum first, then candidate no. second.